# Is this a good way to log a method and its parameters using a decorator?

Tags: python, logging, decorator

So I am trying to create a decorator function that logs the method and its arguments. Here is the decorator function I have created:

```
def logInstanceMethod(infoMessage=None):
  def logFunction(f):
    def function(self,*args, **kwdargs):
      #Info Logging
      if infoMessage is None:
        logging.info("Running method: " + f.__code__.co_name)
      else:
        logging.info(infoMessage)

      #Debug logging
      logging.debug('Running method: ' + f.__code__.co_name)

      if len(args) > 0:
        logging.debug("With args: ")
        for arg in args:
          logging.debug(arg)
      if len(kwdargs) > 0:
        logging.debug("With keyword args: ")
        for kwdarg in kwdargs:
          logging.debug(kwdarg)

      return(f(self, *args, **kwdargs))
    return(function)
  return(logFunction)
```

It works and if I were to use it on the following method:

```
@logInstanceMethod("Method A is running...")
def methodA(self, a):
    print("You ran this function with the parameters: " + a)
```

And then run with `loggingLevel=DEBUG`:

```
methodA('MyParam')
```

It will log:

```
INFO Method A is running...
DEBUG Running method: methodA
DEBUG With args:
DEBUG MyParam
```

And it will print:

```
You ran this function with the parameters: MyParam
```

So the above decorator function does 100% of what I want it to do, but in order for the function to run I need to have the line: `return(f(self, *args, **kwdargs))`. I do not like this because that means that the function being called properly is dependent on that line of code. Is there anyway to get the method that is being logged to still execute without returning the function directly in the logging decorator method? This seems like bad design to me, even if it works.

Comment: It's not bad design, that's how you're *supposed* to do it. Yes, you need to call the function if you want it to be called; you're *replacing* it with the wrapper.

Comment: Ok, so will using `function(self, *args, **kwdargs)` ensure that I can use the logInstanceMethod decorator function on ANY instance method regardless of the arguments for the specific instance method? I just want to make sure that the above is the correct implementation.

Comment: Then write tests, and make sure of it.